# In php, may I enforce the type of the returned values (from methods), (unittest, mock)?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

here are two methods:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function add ($a, $b)
{
    return $a+$b;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray ($a, $b)
{
    return array($a, $b);
}
```

based on PhPDoc and the code itself, nobody can question what the methods result.
But what if Im mocking them with Phpunit?

```
$this->getMock ('MyClass');
$this->expects($this->once())->method('add')->willReturn(array(1,2,3,4));
$this->expects($this->once())->method('toArray')->willReturn(7);
```

in this example, I purposely failed the types of the result values. But nobody will drop an exception "hey, type mismatch!". I know its Php, but can I somehow enforce the types?

Comment: You can, with php 7.

Comment: [Not yet, but soon (November) with PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types)

Answer (score 1):

Not with PhpDoc, but since PHP 7, you can do the following

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

class MyClass
{

    public function add ($a, $b) : int
    {
        return $a+$b;
    }

    public function toArray ($a, $b) : array
    {
        return array($a, $b);
    }

}
```

The `declare(strict_types=1)` line is important because otherwise wrong types will be coerced without error:

> [Strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) also has an effect on return type declarations. In the default weak mode, returned values will be coerced to the correct type if they are not already of that type. In strong mode, the returned value must be of the correct type, otherwise a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php]) will be thrown.

Source: [Manual for "Returning Values"](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)